# What is the difference between of torch.Tensor(0.2566) and 0.2566 in pytorch

Tags: pytorch

When I write like this:
`self.register_buffer('scale', 0.2256)` , It will report error:
`raise TypeError("cannot assign '{}' object to buffer '{}' "` 
However, When I write `self.register_buffer('scale', torch.Tensor(0.2256))` ,It works. Why? I want to known What is the difference between of torch.Tensor(0.2566) and 0.2566 in pytorch?

Than you~~

Answer (score 2):

One is a `torch.Tensor` object, the other is a literal `int`.

Function [`register_buffer`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html?highlight=register_buffer#torch.nn.Module.register_buffer:%7E:text=tensor%20(Tensor%20or%20None)) expects a `torch.Tensor`, not an `int`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `register_buffer` everything in torch program, it is for learnable parameters, and I guess, your `scale` is not.

```
new_img = torch.nn.functional.conv2d( 
      input = ...  # Tensor goes here, probably NOT register_buffer-ed
      weight = ... # Tensor goes here, may be register_buffer-ed, because weights typically learnable
      stride = scale # just number
      ...
      )
```

And probably, you don't need all this at all, just use nn ops in object form like  `torch.nn.Conv2d` instead of `torch.nn.functional.conv2d`, it will do technical job for you.
Also, Ivan is right, of course.